# Compute covariance matrix using Excel

Tags: excel, matrix, statistics, covariance

In Excel, I have 10 columns of data from column A to column J, and each column has 1000 rows from row 1 to row 1000. I wonder how to compute the 10 x 10 covariance matrix of the 10 columns of data in Excel?

My partial solution is based on dollar signs and copying formulas:

First I input in a cell a formula  `=covar($A1:$A1000,A1:A1000)`.

Then I copy and paste the formula to the cells on the right of the first cell, which gives me `=covar($A1:$A1000,B1:B1000)` ... `=covar($A1:$A1000,J1:J1000)`.

Now I don't know how I can get `=covar(B1:B1000,A1:A1000)` ... `=covar(J1:J1000,A1:A1000)`, because if I copy and paste the formula to the cells below the first cell, I will get `=covar($A2:$A1001,A2:A1001)`, ..., `=covar($A1000:$A2001,A1000:A2001)` instead.

Thanks!

Comment: something doesn't quite make sense in your question... what exactly do you want the second and subsequent rows to be?  (by the way if you want to anchor the row numbers use `A$1`, or anchor rows and columns `$A$1`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make the formula "copy-proof" you can make use of the `=OFFSET()` function in combination with row and column indices. Example:

- in **L1...U1** enter numbers **1, 2, 3, ... 10**
- in **K2...K11** enter numbers **1, 2, 3, ... 10**
- now copy-proof references to one of the 10 columns **A...J**. This can be obtained by:

  - `=OFFSET($A$1:$A$1000,0,L$1-1)` to follow the horizontal index
  - `=OFFSET($A$1:$A$1000,0,$K2-1)` to follow the vertical index
- and finally you combine the 2 above into

  ```
  =COVAR(OFFSET($A$1:$A$1000,0,L$1-1),OFFSET($A$1:$A$1000,0,$K2-1))
  ```
- this formula that you enter in **L2**, copy into **L2..U11** to obtain your 10x10 matrix

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks! (1) I wonder what the second and third arguments of OFFSET mean? (2) If there are 1000 columns instead of 10, how will you  accomplish the first two steps efficiently, or do you switch to another method different from what is described in your reply?

Comment: @Tim (1) OFFSET(reference,rows,cols,height,width) ... for more details consult Excel Help <F1> .... (2) I wouldn't use Excel which (max 256 cols), so max ca 125 col's could theoretically be done with the matrix in same tab, otherwise 255 cols with matrix in different tab ... it's a question of time and patience; for > 20 col's or so I would more likely do a VBA function calculating n covariances in one shot